# Customizing Homebrew’s std_cmake_args without modifying the installed source

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

How might one alter or customize the contents of the Ruby list that Homebrew furnishes to its formulae as `std_cmake_args` – globally, and not on a case-by-base basis?

It is easy enough to grep and patch the source, of course – but seeing as Homebrew’s `update` command will clobber such modifications, I would rather take a less directly intrusive route.

Comment: Maybe provide an example of specifically what you are wanting to change (yes i realize it's `std_cmake_args`), but showing what you want to do might be helpful.

Comment: @l'L'l Sure – the default cmake arguments would be a good point of global control: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb#L579-L589 … to specify defaults such as alternative compilers (e.g. brewed clang), compile flags (e.g. c++11/c++14 defaults), cosmetic options (e.g. turning off CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE even during a `brew install --verbose` invocation would ease my eyes, but wouldn’t make the grade as an upstream PR) and so forth. Does that help?

Comment: How about using `GNU patch` to automate re-application of your patches after `brew update`...